# How to correctly specify the conditions for disabling functions?

Tags: javascript, jquery

Please, help!
There are two blocks (there can be more blocks), in each block there is a checkbox, two selects and an element that needs to be hidden/showed depending on the selected select options.
When one of the checkboxes is enabled, one of the selects should stop hiding/showing the desired element, but only in the block in which it is all located.

Functions that hide/show the required element depending on the selected select options work as expected.
The problem is that I cannot correctly specify the conditions that these functions will disable depending on the value of the checkbox, and only in the block in which this checkbox is located.

I can't change the HTML either because it's wordpress.

What should I put in "if" to make it work properly?

```js
$(document).on('change', 'input.checkbox', function (evt) {
  const variation = evt.target.closest('.variation');
  const checkbox = evt.target;
  const on = checkbox.matches('input.checkbox:checked') && 'on' === checkbox.value;
 
  if ((variation && on) == true){ // If the checkbox is enabled
    console.log('On');
      $(document).on('change', '.show select', function (evt) {
        const variation = evt.target.closest('.variation');
        const select = evt.target;
        const showDate = select.matches('[name*="vb"]') && ['notify', 'yes'].includes(select.value); 
        variation.querySelector('.date').classList.toggle('visible', showDate);
      });
  }
  
  else { // If the checkbox is not enabled
    console.log('Off');
      $(document).on('change', '.vss select', function (evt) {
        const variation = evt.target.closest('.variation');
        const select = evt.target;
        const showDate = select.matches('[name*="vss"]') && 'onbackorder' === select.value;
        variation.querySelector('.date').classList.toggle('visible', showDate);
      });
  }
  
});
```

```css
.variations {
  padding: 20px;
  background-color: #ededed;
  font-size: 20px;
}

.variation {
  padding: 20px;
  background-color: #e3e3e3;
}

.variation:first-child {
  background-color: #f5f5f5;
}

.date {
  display: none;
}

.date.visible {
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="variations">
 <div class="variation"><b>First variation</b>
  <input type="checkbox" class="checkbox" name="vms[0]">
  <div class="show">
   select 1
   <select style="" id="backorders0" name="vb[0]">    
     <option value="no">Do not allow</option>
     <option value="notify">Allow but notify client</option> 
     <option value="yes" selected>Allow</option>
   </select>
  </div>
  <div>
   <p class="vss">
    select 2
    <select style="" id="vss0" name="vss[0]">
     <option value="instock" >In stock</option>
     <option value="outofstock">Out of stock</option>
     <option value="onbackorder" selected >Pre-order</option>
    </select>
   </p>
   <p class="date"><input value="It needs to be hidden/showed"></p> 
  </div>
 </div>
 
 <div class="variation"><b>Second variation</b>
  <input type="checkbox" class="checkbox" name="vms[1]">
   <div class="show">
    select 1
    <select style="" id="backorders1" name="vb[1]">  
     <option value="no" selected>Do not allow</option>
     <option value="notify">Allow but notify client</option>
     <option value="yes" >Allow</option>
    </select>
   </div>
   <div>
    <p class="vss">
     select 2
     <select style="" id="vss1" name="vss[1]">
      <option value="instock" >In stock</option>
      <option value="outofstock" selected>Out of stock</option>
      <option value="onbackorder" >Pre-order</option>
     </select>
    </p>
    <p class="date"><input value="It needs to be hidden/showed"></p> 
   </div>
 </div>
</div>
```

Comment: It's not clear to me what is supposed to become disabled when a checkbox becomes checked.

Comment: @76484, If the checkbox is enabled, then "select 1" shows/hides the ".date" element if the "Pre-order" option is selected. At the same time "select 2" does not respond. If the checkbox is disabled, then vice versa.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For this sort of problem where there is a lot of dependent state to manage, I would move all of that management into a single function that can encapsulate all of the logic. We could pass the function the container element - the `.variation` - so that it can worry about just the inputs within a specific variant. The event handlers that need to update the state can call this function, passing the associated container element. Here is an example:

```js
const updateState = $variation => {
  const $checkbox = $variation.find('input.checkbox');
  const $select1 = $variation.find('.show select');
  const $select2 = $variation.find('.vss select');
  
  const isChecked = $checkbox.is(':checked');
  const select2Val = $select2.val();
  
  $select1.attr('disabled', isChecked);
  $select2.attr('disabled', !isChecked);
  $variation.find('.date').toggle(isChecked && select2Val === 'onbackorder');
}

$(document).on('change', 'input.checkbox', function () {
  const $variation = $(this).closest('.variation');
  updateState($variation);
});

$(document).on('change', '.vss select', function () {
  const $variation = $(this).closest('.variation');
  updateState($variation);
});

$('.variation').each(function () {
  updateState($(this));
});
```

```css
.variations {
  padding: 20px;
  background-color: #ededed;
  font-size: 20px;
}

.variation {
  padding: 20px;
  background-color: #e3e3e3;
}

.variation:first-child {
  background-color: #f5f5f5;
}

.date {
  display: none;
}

.date.visible {
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="variations">
  <div class="variation"><b>First variation</b>
    <input type="checkbox" class="checkbox" name="vms[0]">
    <div class="show">
      select 1
      <select style="" id="backorders0" name="vb[0]">
        <option value="no">Do not allow</option>
        <option value="notify">Allow but notify client</option>
        <option value="yes" selected>Allow</option>
      </select>
    </div>
    <div>
      <p class="vss">
        select 2
        <select style="" id="vss0" name="vss[0]">
          <option value="instock">In stock</option>
          <option value="outofstock">Out of stock</option>
          <option value="onbackorder" selected>Pre-order</option>
        </select>
      </p>
      <p class="date"><input value="It needs to be hidden/showed"></p>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="variation"><b>Second variation</b>
    <input type="checkbox" class="checkbox" name="vms[1]">
    <div class="show">
      select 1
      <select style="" id="backorders1" name="vb[1]">
        <option value="no" selected>Do not allow</option>
        <option value="notify">Allow but notify client</option>
        <option value="yes">Allow</option>
      </select>
    </div>
    <div>
      <p class="vss">
        select 2
        <select style="" id="vss1" name="vss[1]">
          <option value="instock">In stock</option>
          <option value="outofstock" selected>Out of stock</option>
          <option value="onbackorder">Pre-order</option>
        </select>
      </p>
      <p class="date"><input value="It needs to be hidden/showed"></p>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you very much! You are my savior! Three days could not solve this problem.

If you don't mind, could you please tell me how to properly insert two select values here:
`$variation.find('.date').toggle(!isChecked && select1Val === ('notify' || 'yes'));`
It seems that I have already tried everything, but it still works fine only if you select one value.

Comment: You are welcome. To include two values it would be: `$variation.find('.date').toggle(!isChecked && select1Val === 'notify' || selectVal === 'yes');`

Comment: Thank you!!! Finally finished it. Only thanks to you, I finally stopped stagnation.